# Factorization Lemma for non-real-valued functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_i,\mathcal A_i),(E,\mathcal E)$ be measurable spaces, $X:\Omega_1\to\Omega_2$ and $Y:\Omega_1\to E$.

> I would like to show that any $Y:\Omega_1\to E$ is $(\sigma(X),\mathcal E)$-measurable if and only if there is a $(\mathcal A_2,\mathcal E)$-measurable $f:\Omega_2\to E$ with $Y=f\circ X$.

We know that this is true for $(E,\mathcal E)=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$. The proof that I'm aware of makes explicitly use of the structure of $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Is there a generalization to more general measurable spaces? Maybe at least for topological spaces $E$ and $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_lemma#Importance_of_the_measure_space) I read that there are conditions on the lemma. Caution: $f$ in the link corresponds with the $Y$ in your question. It is demanded that $Y$ is scalar.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263863/does-the-doob-dynkin-lemma-hold-for-any-measurable-space-that-separates-points